# Mapping domain subdirectory to a specific port using Apache reverse proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache2

I am running a docker app which is accessible on port 8334. I can access it from http://ip.ad.dr.ess:8334 . I want to access it from https://domain.name/subfolder (I already have SSL certs configured for domain.name). Here is what I tried to add in virtualhost:

`ProxyPass /subfolder http://ip.ad.dr.ess:8334`

`ProxyPassReverse /subfolder http://ip.ad.dr.ess:8334`

It takes me to an error page specific to that app. So I assume the reverse proxy worked but then something went wrong.

Now when I visit http://ip.ad.dr.ess:8334 , it redirects to http://ip.ad.dr.ess:8334/login . My guess is, https://domain.name/subfolder is unable to redirect to https://domain.name/subfolder/login and that's the reason for my error.

I have tried to use redirect rules. For example:
`RewriteRule ^/subfolder(.*)$ http://ip.ad.dr.ess:8334/$1 [P]`
But that didn't solve the issue.

What can I do to make it work?